# Android login remeber me checkbox

Tags: android, authentication, checkbox, android-edittext

I have created a login for an application.  I got it that if you type in the username and password then click on the checkbox it remembers the username and password.  However, if you make any changes after you click the checkbox the they are not saved. I am wondering if there is a way to fix this and how would I got about doing this. What I am thinking is when click on the edittext it continually saves what is in the editext.  Basically, something that would dynamically saves while the user changes the password or username while the checkbox is clicked.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_log_in);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userName);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.invalid);
    error.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.remember);


    LoadPreferences();
    LoadPreferences1();
}


public void rememberInfo(View view) {
        SavePrefernces("MEM1", name.getText().toString());
        SavePrefernces("MEM2", password.getText().toString());


}

private void LoadPreferences1() {
    SharedPreferences shardPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String strSavedMem2 = shardPreferences.getString("MEM2", "");
    password.setText(strSavedMem2);


}

private void LoadPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences shardPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String strSavedMem1 = shardPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");
    name.setText(strSavedMem1);


}

private void SavePrefernces(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences shardPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shardPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I think would be to do the saving of the login details at the time of pressing the login (or whatever) button. So when the button is pressed, get the values from both the `EditText`s and store them in the `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are calling `Saveprefernces` when the checkBox is checked. Instead you should do it once you know that your sign In is success, so that only a valid pair of username:password is saved